# gradle test runs my test class, but not a custom test task

Tags: java, testing, junit, build, gradle

This is my test class:

```
public class RoutingResponseRegressionOneByOne {


    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
        routingClient = injector.getInstance(IRoutingClient.class);
        System.out.println("in RoutingResponseRegressionOneByOne:: oneTimeSetUp");
    }
```

I added a task to my build.gradle

```
task testRegression(type: Test) {
    systemProperties['test.single'] = '\'RoutingResponseRegressionOneByOne\''
    //systemProperty 'test.single', System.getProperty('test.single', '\'RoutingResponseRegressionOneByOne\'')
}
```

When I run `"test"` from the intellij this is the output

however when I `"testRegression"` from the intellij this is the output:

what should I fix in order for `"testRegression"` to run only this test class ?

Comment: What is the output you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an argument to your task with `P` and use the [TestFilter](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html).

In this link you will find a complete example for the filter usage. Below I attached a code of a custom `automationTest` task that runs tests from a specific folder.

```
task automationTest(type: Test) {
    //search for an argument called 'single'. if exists, use it as a test filter
    if (project.hasProperty('single')) {
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching "*${project.property('single')}*"
        }
    }
    useTestNG()

    description = "Runs Automation Tests"
    testClassesDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/automation")
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

run it as: `gradle -Psingle=MyTest automationTest`